# .sol files editor for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking some editor for **.sol** files (LSO/Local Shared Object).

Can you please suggest one? I have looked but could not find any for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [.minerva](https://mariani.life/projects/minerva-air/), it is capable of editing SOL files and is an OS independent web app. The description says this:

> .minerva is a Flash Local Shared Object editor built based on the AMF3 specification and the AMF0 specification. .minerva is capable of reading and writing all known data types successfully.

I've tried it and it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Why not download one of these softwares and run them using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)?

According to [Wine's website](http://www.winehq.org/):

> Open Source Software for running Windows applications on other operating systems

I'm a flash developer too, from what I know, there is no such software for editing **.sol** files on ubuntu, last time I needed it, I ran a VirtualBox machine with Windows 7 installed.